# How to use Normalized Mutual Information to evaluate overlapping community from igraph in python

Tags: python, igraph

Given the increasing popularity of algorithms for overlapping clustering, in particular in social network analysis, quantitative measures are needed to measure the accuracy of a method. I need know how to use Normalized Mutual Information (NMI, available in igraph) to evaluate overlapping community from igraph in python.

This function: http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/python/

```
compare_communities(comm1, comm2, method='nmi', remove_none=False)
```

where

```
method = "nmi"
```

and `comm1` and `comm2` is a OverlappingClustering Object (http://cneurocvs.rmki.kfki.hu/igraph/doc/python/igraph.clustering.OverlappingClustering-class.html)

I tried this:

```
cl = igraph.Clustering([(0,), (0,), (0,1), (1,), (1,), ()])
```

But, it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "multilevel_overlapping.py", line 94, in <module>
        cl = igraph.Clustering([(0,), (0,), (0,1), (1,), (1,), ()])
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/igraph/clustering.py", line 92, in __init__
        self._len = max(m for m in self._membership if m is not None)+1
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

Also, tried this:

```
cl = igraph.OverlappingClustering([(0,), (0,), (0,1), (1,), (1,), ()])
```

But, it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multilevel_overlapping.py", line 94, in <module>
    cl = igraph.OverlappingClustering([(0,), (0,), (0,1), (1,), (1,), ()])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OverlappingClustering'
```

Would anyone can help me to use NMI function?

Comment: The documentation states clearly, that the list parameter for the `Clustering` constructor should contain a list of integers, i.e. cluster numbers. Why do you call with a list of tuples? 

"@param membership: the membership list -- that is, the cluster
          index in which each element of the set belongs to."

Comment: This (`cl = Clustering([(0,), (0,), (0,1), (1,), (1,), ()])`) is a example extracted from igraph documentation. My objective is that a single vertex can be the member of multiple clusters (or even none of them)

Comment: Well, for the version I've found on the web, the documentation of `Clustering`'s constructor doesn't allow that. And the exception you quote suggests that this is the version you're using - and it allows only one cluster for each element. Perhaps there is some problem with the version you're using, or there is more than one `Clustering` class?

Comment: I'll rephrase the question. My objective is only use NMI to measure the accuracy of two overlapping community structure.

Comment: FYI, the current documentation is here: http://igraph.org/python/#docs

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading. But, I think that was removed the overlapping communtiy.

Comment: There isn't need to use OverlappingClustering. OverlappingClustering isn't important, can be any data structure. I need only evaluate overlapping community from NMI. The NMI function is important.

Comment: How would you define NMI for overlapping clusterings?

Comment: @Tamás http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.2515.pdf or http://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.1218.pdf (Página 16, Appendix B. Comparing partitions)

Comment: Thanks; I was not aware of this and igraph's NMI measure implements a different measure that is suitable for disjoint communities only: Danon L, Diaz-Guilera A, Duch J, Arenas A: Comparing community structure identification. J Stat Mech P09008, 2005.

Comment: @Tamás I open a new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135768/normalized-mutual-information-to-evaluate-overlapping-community-finding-algorith. This post is most específic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in the documentation. The class you're referring to is called `OverlappingClustering` not `Clustering`. Therefore try this:

```
 cl = OverlappingClustering([(0,), (0,), (0,1), (1,), (1,), ()])
```